# Default SSL context init failed: SunX509 KeyManagerFactory not available

Tags: spring, ssl-certificate, resttemplate, weblogic-10.x, java-5

I have an exception when I try to do a post call using restTemplate from my local app hosted on weblogic 10 to an authentication service

I've tried many things like using TLSv1.2 with java 5 (using BouncyCastle provider) by :

1. Adding the option  -DUseSunHttpHandler=true
2. Installing the required certifications
3. Adding bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar to the jdk
4. And this to the java.security :

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
```

At the end I have this exception :

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Default SSL context init failed: SunX509 KeyManagerFactory not available; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Default SSL context init failed: SunX509 KeyManagerFactory not available
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:302)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Default SSL context init failed: SunX509 KeyManagerFactory not available
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:372)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleClientHttpRequest.java:58)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:438)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Weblogic 10 was released 12 years ago, Java 5 got its last public release 10 years ago. Issues like this are exactly the reason why you'd need to move on from such an ancient tech stack. I know you probably can't decide that ...

Comment: And to be slightly more useful: [This mailing list thread](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/BCJSSE-JDK5-and-SSLSocketFactory-getDefault-td4659306.html) seems to be by someone who managed to get this working (not specifically for WebLogic, but enabling TLSv1.2 by default on Java 5).

Comment: I totally agree with you @JoachimSauer, anyway the app will die in a few months, but still need this little call to be done for this period. After all I'm on latest technologies beside this

Comment: What is the OS you are running WebLogic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the missed parts of my configuration to success my post calls :

In addition of using TLSv1.2 above, I had to have this in the java.security file of the JDK :

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
```

And then got this error when tested my code :

`Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64`

To fix this I've added the https.cipherSuites param as below :

```
System.setProperty("https.cipherSuites", "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA");
```

You can either put this when starting the app : 
`-Dhttps.cipherSuites="SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"`

PS: Pay attention! https.cipherSuites is supported in HttpsURLConnection (in case youy use RestTemplate)

Then it just worked :D